# toggle div using css - show/hide div located relative position to buttons

Tags: html, css

three divs, each div contains parent div, an input, and a hidden div.
I want to be able to show the hidden div that follows the checkbox.
I want to toggle a div display when I click the checkbox, 
If the checkbox is checked I want the next div to be seen.
I wrote a css code but no matter which checkbox I check the only div that is toggeled is the first one

this is the html

```
<div class="check-btn">

    <input id="myid" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>

<div class="check-btn">

    <input id="myid" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>
<div class="check-btn">


    <input id="myid" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>
```

this is the css:

```
div input {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.check-btn label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-btn input {
  display: none;
}

.clicker {
  background: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.hiddendiv {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.check-btn input:checked ~ .hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
```

How can I do that each checkbox will control the div that has common parent.

My code is here:
https://codepen.io/davsev/pen/JjdJYQw

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to toggle all of these `.hiddendiv`?

Comment: if click the first cb I want to toggle the first `.hiddendiv` div,  if click the second cb I want to toggle the second `.hiddendiv` div and so on

Comment: I believe it can be achieved through Javascript.. Are you okay to include ```JS``` in your code??

Comment: no, only css @ManirajMurugan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your are using multiple `id` with value `myid` which has to be unique. Each of your label has value `for="myid2` which actually triggers only the first checkbox which has been found (first checkbox with `id="myid"`).

I've updated each of your checkboxes to contains `id="someUniqueID"` and label `for="someUniqueID"` to be unique.

Working example:

```css
div input {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.check-btn label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-btn input {
  display: none;
}

.clicker {
  background: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.hiddendiv {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.check-btn input:checked ~ .hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-btn">

    <input id="myid" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>

<div class="check-btn">

    <input id="myid2" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid2" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>
<div class="check-btn">


    <input id="myid3" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid3" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost got it. I tried assigning a unique id to each input and it worked: (same css)

```html
<div class="check-btn">

    <input id="myid1" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid1" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>

<div class="check-btn">

    <input id="myid2" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid2" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>
<div class="check-btn">


    <input id="myid3" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid3" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>
```

The **checked** value it's being set to the first *myid*. That's why it wasn't working on the rest.